# how to get all category,subcategory from amazon mws?

Tags: php, amazon-mws

How can I get all categories using Amazon MWS. Is there any API to get categories? We have access to the `token client id`.

Comment: did you already look at MWS API documentation?

Comment: yes , but no any API  for get categories

Comment: Yep, looks that way. Well, no categories for you, then (using MWS API, at least)

Comment: Is it any another way to get all categories.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using

```
$url = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01" . '?' . $url_string . "&Signature=" . $signature;
```

or something similar you can find the category for an item

ItemAttributes->ProductGroup so if you search with the API you can return the main category for an item with either UPC or ISBN as well as a keyword search.

the list has changed since the last time Amazon officially published it in 2005 but if you go to amazon.com and click departments that will give you the small list ( if you click on the gray link in the search bar that says all that will also give you a bigger list.